# Quering Web API 2.2 with lowerCamelCase

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am using Web API 2.2 with the `[EnableQuery]` like this:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    private MyContext db = new MyContext();


    [EnableQuery]
    public IQueryable<Product> GetProducts()
    {
        return db.Products;
    }
}
```

Once I am using `CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver` I would like to perform an OData query like this: `api/products/?$expand=categories` instead of `api/products/?$expand=Categories`.

I tested the OData v4 (which I dont want use because the DateTime properties) using `ODataController` and it works:

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EnableLowerCamelCase();
```

So, I wonder if is this possible with ApiController ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following steps:

1. Define a custom EnableQueryAttribute:

   ```
   public class MyEnableQueryAttribute:EnableQueryAttribute
   {
       public override IEdmModel GetModel(Type elementClrType, HttpRequestMessage request,
           HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
       {
           // Get model for the request
           IEdmModel model = request.ODataProperties().Model;

           if (model == null)
           {
               // user has not configured anything or has registered a model without the element type
               // let's create one just for this type and cache it in the action descriptor
               model = actionDescriptor.Properties.GetOrAdd("System.Web.OData.Model+" + elementClrType.FullName, _ =>
               {
                   ODataConventionModelBuilder builder =
                       new ODataConventionModelBuilder(actionDescriptor.Configuration, isQueryCompositionMode: true);
                   builder.EnableLowerCamelCase();
                   EntityTypeConfiguration entityTypeConfiguration = builder.AddEntityType(elementClrType);
                   builder.AddEntitySet(elementClrType.Name, entityTypeConfiguration);
                   IEdmModel edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
                   Contract.Assert(edmModel != null);
                   return edmModel;
               }) as IEdmModel;
           }

           Contract.Assert(model != null);
           return model;
       }
   }
   ```
2. Add it to the actions in the controller:

   ```
   public class ProductsController : ApiController
   {
       [MyEnableQuery]
       public IHttpActionResult Get()
       {
           IList<Product> products=new List<Product>();
           products.Add(new Product() { Id = 1, Name = "Name1",Category=new Category(){Id=1,Name="Category1" }});
           products.Add(new Product() { Id = 2, Name = "Name2", Category = new Category() { Id = 2, Name = "Category2" } });


           return Ok(products.AsQueryable<Product>());
       }
   }
   ```

then it is able to query with camel case:

```
GET http://localhost:12568/api/Products?$expand=category
```

I've put the whole solution here: https://github.com/tanjinfu/WebApiODataSamples/tree/master/EnableCamelCaseForApiController, FYI.